# When does an integer divide a fraction?

Tags: number-theory

This might seem like a stupid question but I've been stuck with it all day. It seems to me that

$c|\frac{a}{b}$  iff $c|a$ & ${c\not{|}{b}}$

but I can't prove it.

Comment: How do you define $c\mid\frac1b$?

Comment: Where are you encountering the notion of an integer dividing (or not dividing) a fraction? The "$\mid$" notation is usually limited to settings with integers on both sides.

Comment: I think we can define $\frac ab=nc$ with $n$ integer. Even for reals I'm not overly shocked by $\frac {\pi}4$ being a divisor of $\frac {\pi}2$.

Comment: @zwim In that case, $b=1$ when the fraction is reduced, so...

Comment: hmm, yeah I was thinking $c=\frac a{nb}$ rational, but for $c$ integer that makes no sense.

Comment: I have seen the notion of $p\mid q$ when $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$ if $q=np$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. However, if $p\in\mathbb{Z}$, then that forces $q\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @BarryCipra group theory

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos why does that matter?

Comment: It matters because I do not know the meaning of that expression and, without knowing it, I am unable to think about your question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the context is the following: for the proof of Syllow theorem, at one point we need to establish that $p|{{p}\choose{i}}$. The book observes that this is the case because p divides the denominator but not the numerator.

Comment: I did not ask for context. I asked for a *definition* of $c\mid\frac ab$.

Comment: The same as always, because we assume $a/b \in \mathbb{Z}$